# How to change the number of rows in a UIPickerView component based on the selected value in another component

Tags: swift, xcode, uipickerview

The Google Calendar app has a feature where you can customize when you want a notification to be sent before an event. If you're unfamiliar with it, it looks like this:

[Google Calendar Custom Notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnNpz.png)

It's essentially a picker view with two components, the first one showing numbers for the user to choose, and the second showing units of time ("minutes", "hours", "days", "weeks"). When the user selects the unit of time, the numbers change. For example, if the user chooses "minutes" as their unit, the first component will show numbers 1 through 60. If they choose "hours", the first component will show 1 through 24. Selecting "days" will show 1 through 28, and "weeks" will show 1 through 4.

I want to develop a similar feature, but when I run my code I get the error "Index out of range". The error occurs in the last function in this chunk of code. In the debug section, the value of "row" is 0. I think the error has to do with the differences in the sizes of the arrays, but I'm not sure. All help is appreciated!

```
import UIKit
class AlarmSet
{
    func timeIntervals() -> [String]
    {
        return ["minutes", "hours", "days", "weeks"]
    }

    func timeValues(time: String) -> [Int]
    {
        switch time
        {
            case "minutes":
                return Array(1...60)
            case "hours":
                return Array(1...24)
            case "days":
                return Array(1...28)
            case "weeks":
                return [1, 2, 3, 4]
            default:
                return [0]
        }
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate 
{

    @IBOutlet weak var addAlarm: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var alarmView: UIPickerView!

    //The first component of the picker displays numbers
    var picker1Options:[Int] = []
    //The second picker displays units of time (minutes, hours, etc.)
    var picker2Options:[String] = []

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        alarmView.delegate = self
        alarmView.dataSource = self
        alarmView.delegate?.pickerView?(alarmView, didSelectRow: 0, inComponent: 0)
        alarmView.delegate?.pickerView?(alarmView, didSelectRow: 0, inComponent: 1)

        alarmView.isHidden = true
        let alarm = AlarmSet();

        picker2Options = alarm.timeIntervals()
        let firstValue = picker2Options[0]
        picker1Options = alarm.timeValues(time: firstValue)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int
    {
        return 2
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
    {
        if component == 1
        {
            return picker2Options.count
        }
        else
        {
            return picker1Options.count
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
    {
        if component == 0 
        {
            return "\(picker1Options[row])"
        } 
        else 
        {
        return "\(picker2Options[row])"
        }
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
    {
        if component == 1
        {
            let alarm = AlarmSet();
            //Out of range error is on this next line
            let currentValue = picker2Options[row]
            picker1Options = alarm.timeValues(time: currentValue)
            pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling

```
alarmView.delegate?.pickerView?(alarmView, didSelectRow: 0, inComponent: 1
```

in your viewDidLoad before you set your picker2Options var, so it's trying to access picker2Options[0] when picker2Options is blank. Set your arrays before calling the delegate method

Comment: In general, it's always good to check `yourArray.indices.contains(yourIndex)` before attempting to access it